# MySQL Group_concat

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wh.uid         ORDER BY wh.id) as property_uid,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wh.folder_name ORDER BY wh.id) as property, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pr.uid)    
FROM warehouse_folders wh
RIGHT JOIN product_property pp ON wh.uid = pp.property_uid
    LEFT  JOIN products pr         ON pr.uid = pp.product_uid 
    WHERE wh.parent_folder_uid     IN (160819192400136, 160819192400134)
    GROUP BY  pr.uid
ORDER BY property
;
```

Результат которого:

[image: Результат выполненного запроса]

Проблема: поле `property` имеет одинаковое наименование - "Зеленый, Майский", но разный `ID` товара (правая колонка). 
Из-за `GROUP BY pr.uid` оно кидает их по разным строкам.

Что я хочу в результате: убрать повторение (т.е -1 строка) , а `id` товара, который имеет одинаковое `property`, поместить рядом.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.property_uid ) AS tproperty_uid,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.property ) AS tproperty, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.pr_uid)
FROM 
(   SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wh.uid         ORDER BY wh.id) AS property_uid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wh.folder_name ORDER BY wh.id) AS property, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pr.uid) AS pr_uid 
    FROM warehouse_folders wh
        RIGHT JOIN product_property pp ON wh.uid = pp.property_uid
        LEFT  JOIN products pr         ON pr.uid = pp.product_uid    
        WHERE wh.parent_folder_uid     IN (160819192400136, 160819192400134)    
    GROUP BY  pp.product_uid
    ORDER BY property   ) AS T
GROUP BY t.property
;
```

Вот решение вопроса.
Результат: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]